# AEM: Disable anchor (link) plugin in inline rich text editor

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm trying to disable(or remove) the anchor/link plugin in an InplaceEditingConfig inside AEM.

So when when I'm editing a text, inline, on a page, I do not want to the anchor plugin. All the others are fine (bold, underline, align etc...).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
      jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
<cq:inplaceEditing jcr:primaryType="cq:InplaceEditingConfig" active="true" configPath="../../dialog/items/tab1/items/text" editorType="text">

</cq:inplaceEditing>
```

Thanks!

M.

Answer (score 4):

In AEM RTE, link is a plugin which provide following dialogs:

- modifylink
- unlink
- anchor

A plugin in RTE can be enabled fully, partially or can be disabled. To do so you need to include plugin node in RTE dialog like:
[image]

For link, i have added links node and added features property. Please note that:

1. If all features of a plugin needs to be activated then features attribute should be String type single valued. And its value should be *
2. If selective features needs to be activated of a plugin, features attribute should be String type multivalue. Add all features as values. Please see this [table](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/operations/page-authoring/rich-text-editor.html) to get list of plugins and features.
3. If plugin needs to be deactivated, then features attribute should be String type multivalue. Keep value empty.